# Extending Measurement<UnitAngle> To Provide Reciprocal Angle

Tags: swift

I am trying to extend a Measurement to return the reciprocal of itself. The following code does not work as it really only extends a UnitAngle which then can't be called on a Measurement:

import Foundation

```
extension UnitAngle {
    func reciprocal(_ angle: Measurement<UnitAngle>) -> Measurement<UnitAngle> {
        var recip = angle.converted(to: .degrees)
        if recip.value < 180 {
            recip.value = recip.value + 180
            return recip.converted(to: angle.unit)
        } else {
            recip.value = recip.value - 180
            return recip.converted(to: angle.unit)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that I can't figure out how to have it only apply to a Measurement. I also looked into making it its own converter as per [Custom measurement unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098748/custom-measurement-unit), but I am returning the same unit that I started with, just the opposite direction. For the time being, I will make it a function in each of the structs where I need it, but that seems repetitive, and an extension of the type would solve my problem and create a simple . notation call. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define an extension of `Measurement` which is constrained to `UnitType` being `UnitAngle`:

```
extension Measurement where UnitType == UnitAngle {
    func reciprocal() -> Measurement {
        var recip = self.converted(to: .degrees)
        if recip.value < 180 {
            recip.value = recip.value + 180
        } else {
            recip.value = recip.value - 180
        }
        return recip.converted(to: self.unit)
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
let a = Measurement(value: 10, unit: UnitAngle.degrees)
print(a) // 10.0 °
print(a.reciprocal()) // 190.0 °

let b = Measurement(value: -.pi/2 , unit: UnitAngle.radians)
print(b) // -1.5707963267948966 rad
print(b.reciprocal()) // 1.5707952034743378 rad
```

A slightly simpler implementation is

```
extension Measurement where UnitType == UnitAngle {
    func reciprocal() -> Measurement {
        var recip = self.converted(to: .degrees)
        recip.value = (recip.value + 180).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
        return recip.converted(to: self.unit)
    }
}
```

Comment: That is a beautiful answer! I knew there had to be a simpler way of finding the reciprocal, but mine worked and I was more worried about extending Measurement. I did not know you could use "where" like that in the extension definition. I will remember that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `Measurement` and constrain `UnitType` to `UnitAngle`:

```
extension Measurement where UnitType == UnitAngle {
    var straightAngle: Double {
        switch unit {
        case .degrees: return 180
        case .radians: return .pi
        default: fatalError()
        }
    }
    var reciprocal: Self {
        let straightAngle = self.straightAngle
        let value = (self.value + straightAngle).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: straightAngle * 2)
        return .init(value: value, unit: unit)
    }
}
```