# Swift how to represent standard atmosphere pressure for unit conversion

Tags: ios, swift

I am making a unit converter app. When dealing with pressure, I found that there are already a few units predefined in Foundation:

```
      UnitPressure.newtonsPerMetersSquared
      UnitPressure.bars
      UnitPressure.poundsForcePerSquareInch
```

But there's no standard atmosphere pressure. (Note that bar is not the same as standard atmosphere pressure, despite that they are close).

I am wondering how do i handle this case?

Comment: [You can define your own units.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49098748/custom-measurement-unit). You just need to know how to convert from the base unit to your unit. 1 standard atmosphere is 101325 N/m^2.

Comment: Is the base unit N/m^2? how do you tell from the API?

Comment: `UnitPressure.baseUnit().symbol` :)

Comment: It's also in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/unitpressure).

Comment: Also, it is the unit expressed in SI units.  1 Newton/m2 is one Pascal. The conventional measure for atmospheric pressure in SI units is *hectopascals* which you get by dividing the pascals figure by 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define your own units very easily:

```
extension UnitPressure {
    static let standardAtmospheres = UnitPressure(
        symbol: "atm", 
        converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 101325)
    )
}

Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitPressure.bars)
    .converted(to: .standardAtmospheres) // 0.9869232667160128 atm
Measurement(value: 1, unit: UnitPressure.standardAtmospheres)
    .converted(to: .bars) // 1.01325 bar
```

The symbol for standard atmospheres is "atm" and 1 atm = 101325 N/m^2  as suggested by [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=standard+atmosphere), hence the magic number used in the code.

Note that N/m^2 is the base unit of [`UnitPressure`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/unitpressure).

> The `UnitPressure` class defines its base unit as `newtonsPerMetersSquared` and provides the following units, which `UnitConverterLinear` converters initialize with the given coefficients: [...]